# Stop jQuery load() from closing tags

Tags: jquery

I'm loading in these 3 files using `jquery.load()`;

```
$('#default-modal .modal-title').load('/app/components/leads/list/create/form-header.html');
$('#default-modal .modal-body').load('/app/components/leads/list/create/form-body.html');
$('#default-modal .modal-footer').load('/app/components/leads/list/create/form-footer.html');
```

However the `form-header.html` file contains an unclosed `<form>` tag, and either `jquery.load()` or the browser is closing this tag immediately at the end of the file. Is there any way to stop it from doing this?

Edit: I see the load method has been deprecated since 1.8, what is the current standard way to load in a html file using jquery/js?

Comment: no... there is no way to do that... when load method creates the corresponding dom structure it will close those elements

Comment: That's what I feared. Okay time to go restructure some code.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely jQuery's doing. Because jQuery manipulates the DOM, it automatically closes tags. The previous `load()` method previously was to jQuery's current `.on("load", ...)` method, and was deprecated to remove the ambiguity. It now is just for AJAX.

Anyway, to solve your problem, I recommend you use the [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

Here's an example based on your code:

```
$.ajax('/app/components/leads/list/create/form-header.html', {
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
       $('#default-modal .modal-title').html(data);
    }
});
```

Edit: It's probably likely that the `.html()` function will auto close the tags as well, now that I think about it. I'll have to test it out.